# How to Hide Launcher Icon and BroadCastReceiver running in the background?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-broadcast

**What I want is  :**  ***`I want to run an application without LAUNCHER ICON and BraodCastReceiver running in the background. I searched And Make a DEMO for it`***

**Result of this  :** ***`Launcher ICON gone but when I reboot the phone BroadCastReceiver dosen't run. What is the possible Solution for this. I added the code what I am trying.`***

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(intent); 

        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

**BroadCastReceiver Class**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "hahahah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.withouticon"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.withouticon.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: @A M Better you start service in the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Service will run what i need, all the time and after reboot the phone @Ram

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
     p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
     finish();  
    }
```

Comment: first time I want to show my layout to the user .... that is necessary ... by this activity run and close at a same time .... seems not effective ,,,,,

Comment: the code is running well  What I wrote above .... device having some problem ... that time